# Histogram in ggplot does not start at zero on X axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

So, this is the first time using ggplot to make a histogram and what I see is that for my data the histogram exported is the one below.

[image]

What I don't like, is the fact that the first bin does not include the zero and it starts at about 5 or 6. Has anyone encountered something like this?

I have used a range of binwidths, from 1 to 20 and it keeps doing it.

Data:

```
structure(list(V1 = c(8, 4.4, 9.4, 29.4, 135.6, 65, 70.9, 15.2, 38.8, 87.2, 5.2, 0.2, 7.8, 46.4, 35.9, 77.4, 34.2, 157.4, 46.4, 19, 43.8, 41.2, 96.8, 25.6, 40.2, 111.8, 111.8, 49.8, 39.4, 9.6, 11.6, 8.6, 44.2, 41, 4.6, 36.2, 12.4, 45.8, 0, 30.8, 134.6, 167.2, 13.8, 56.6, 112.3, 13.6, 18.8, 18.2, 7, 40.4, 30.8, 130.2, 234.6, 106.2, 87.2, 15, 7.6, 63, 18, 2.6, 28, 24, 153.2, 24.4, 69.6, 27, 134, 181.6, 46, 85.4, 18.6, 32, 83.6, 42.6, 32.8, 127.5, 92.8, 122, 129.6, 35.4, 20.6, 88, 14.8, 12.8, 33.8, 58.6, 104.2, 0.2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -88L))
```

Code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
dat = read.csv('mo.csv')
p2=ggplot(dat, aes(x = dat$v2)) +
  geom_histogram(color="black", fill="grey40", bins=25)+ 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 255, 25), limits = c(0,255), expand=c(0,0))+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),limits = c(0,16.5), breaks = pretty(dat$v2, n = 140))
p2
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [how to make a great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2359523) to aid others in answering your questions. Without seeing data, and the code you are using, it's hard to say. You likely don't have data below 5 or 6.

Comment: This answer might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46453008/8583393

Comment: Thank you for answering. My whole data set contains only about 100 values. Those below 5 or 6 are these:

0,

0.2,

0.2,

2.6,

4.4,

4.6,

5.2.

Binwidth is set to 10 for the image above.

Comment: Hello @userwrld_is, please post your code and data into your original question.

Comment: Hello @Roman. I just updated the question. Hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks. I removed the Google Drive link and pasted the data using the `dput()` command. This way others can reproduce it with one line of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = dat$V1)) +
  geom_histogram(color="black", fill="grey40", bins=20)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,250,25))+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),limits = c(0,16.5), breaks = pretty(dat$V1, n = 140))
```

This seems to be what you're looking for. Although 25 bins looks way better than 20, imo.

Comment: Hello @Jared C. I can't remove `limits = c(0,255)` because otherwise the `breaks = seq(0, 255, 25)` does not work. Thank you.

Edit: It works but it goes only up to 225 and I want it to go up too 250. That's why I am putting the limits command.

Comment: Try my updated code. It starts at 0 and includes 250 at the end.

Comment: Thanks man. That's better. Mine, hadn't been working because `expand = c(0,0)` was after `breaks`

Answer (score -1):

Using your data and the simplest possible visualization, I get:

[image: 1]

Are you sure you are using the right variable (column)? Try to run the code below.

By the way: in ggplot2, you do not need to specify the data source in the `aes()` call. Also, using `<-` as the assignment operator (not `=`, contrary to many programming languages) is [recommended practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741820/what-are-the-differences-between-and-in-r) in most cases.

#### Code

```
ggplot(data, aes(V1)) +
    geom_histogram(color = "black", fill = "grey40", bins = 25)
```

#### Data

```
data <- structure(list(V1 = c(8, 4.4, 9.4, 29.4, 135.6, 65, 70.9, 15.2, 38.8, 87.2, 5.2, 0.2, 7.8, 46.4, 35.9, 77.4, 34.2, 157.4, 46.4, 19, 43.8, 41.2, 96.8, 25.6, 40.2, 111.8, 111.8, 49.8, 39.4, 9.6, 11.6, 8.6, 44.2, 41, 4.6, 36.2, 12.4, 45.8, 0, 30.8, 134.6, 167.2, 13.8, 56.6, 112.3, 13.6, 18.8, 18.2, 7, 40.4, 30.8, 130.2, 234.6, 106.2, 87.2, 15, 7.6, 63, 18, 2.6, 28, 24, 153.2, 24.4, 69.6, 27, 134, 181.6, 46, 85.4, 18.6, 32, 83.6, 42.6, 32.8, 127.5, 92.8, 122, 129.6, 35.4, 20.6, 88, 14.8, 12.8, 33.8, 58.6, 104.2, 0.2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -88L))
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I am using the same data and at first I get the same plot as you. It's also weird how this time, the bin starts before zero. it's just the appearance that changes when I add `limits = c(0,250)`.