# How to make histogram in ggplot2 start at zero on X axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

When using `geom_histogram()` to plot histogram, the plot will always not start at zero as expect. See my example below:

```
set.seed(20) 
randomnum <- rnorm(40) 
data <- data.frame(number = randomnum[randomnum > 0]) 
ggplot(data, aes(x = number)) +  
  geom_histogram(color="black", fill="grey40")
```

[image]

Even the data do not contain negative number, the histgram will start at a negative value. The code below may see more clear:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = number)) +
  geom_histogram(color="black", fill="grey40", binwidth = 0.1) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0, seq(0, 2, 0.1)))
```

[image]

The histgram will start at `-0.1`, but the original data do not contain the negative data.
My ideal plot is the x axis will start at 0, and every plot bar share the same width. The plot may be like this:

[image]

There are some simmilar questions in stackoverflow, [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53565242/histogram-in-ggplot-does-not-start-at-zero-on-x-axis) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41486027/ggplot2-how-to-align-the-bars-of-a-histogram-with-the-x-axis/). They change the parameter in `scale_x_continuous()`. But it only changes the axis scales and labels and do not solve my problem.

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46453008/680068 from your links should answer this question, too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the solution is:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = number)) +
  geom_histogram(color="black", fill="grey40", binwidth = 0.1, 
                 boundary = 0, closed = "left") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0, seq(0, 2, 0.1)))
```

The `boundary` is the key parameter!

Comment: `closed = "left"` is not useful here however.